# how to handle django many to many mapper object

Tags: python, django

i have model :

```
class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)               # Tag name
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):   
        return unicode(self.tag)


class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                          # Store Name
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)                            # Store Popularity Number
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=storeImageDir)                              # Store Image 
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                                       # This is the text you see in the URL
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                  # Time at which store is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                                   # Time at which store is updated
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.storeName)

    def StoreTags(self):
        return unicode(self.storeTags.all())
```

It is displaying [] under StoreTags
this is storesAdmin class:

```
class storesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('storeName','storeDescription','storeURL',
                    'storePopularityNumber','storeImage',
                    'storeSlug','createdAt','createdAt','StoreTags'
                    )
```

Why it is displaying like that i even tried to convert it into unicode but it not working..

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using CamelCase in Model Fields. [Django Codigo Style - Model Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

"Field names should be all lowercase, using underscores instead of camelCase."

Avoid using CamelCase in functions and methods.

"Use underscores, not camelCase, for variable, function and method names (i.e. poll.get_unique_voters(), not poll.getUniqueVoters)."

Try choosing another name for storetags method. Maybe it clashes with storetags field name.django hash object

Answer (score 0):

Try with code:

```
models
class Tags(models.Model):
    #...
    def __unicode__(self):   
        return '%s' % self.tag

class Stores(models.Model):
    #...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.storeTags.tag

admin, list_display is not supported to ManyToMany, i'm remove storetags
class storesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('storename','storedescription','storeurl',
                'storepopularitynumber','storeimage',
                'storeslug','createdat','createdat'
                )
```

Tell me if it works correctly.

Comment: I'm update my answer.

Comment: Try this :def StoreTags(self):
              return '\n'.join([s.tag for s in self.storeTags.all()])